# PHP CronJob to Run on Every 30th Minute of the Hour

Tags: php, cron

Start of the day I set database with message to send in 8.30AM to 9.30AM

8.30AM -> "Some Message"

9.30AM -> "Another Message"

...

9.30PM -> "Sign Off"

I need to write cronjob to run this. How to set cronjob to run in **every 30th minute** of the hour?

I need how to set up cronjob to run in every 30th minute of the hour. (eg. 8.30, 9.30) My server is in UTC and I need to run the script on Asia/Karachi timezone.

I'm setting the cronjob from a shared cpanel. So I don't have privilege to change server timezone.

Comment: http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference

Comment: I am sure there is a manual or a tutorial somewhere out there on the web

Comment: @RiggsFolly Read the question again. I have updated it with more informatoin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
00  *   *   *   *   php /home/user/public_html/test/test.php
```

Since server is in UTC, set job to run in every hour's starting minute it runs at every 30th minute in my timezone (GMT+0530)

Answer (score 1):

You can run the cron job every 30 mins of every hour:

```
*/30 * * * * curl www.example.com/functionName
```

Comment: @user2473015 can you send me your code line of cronjob so I can take a look into.

Comment: 00  *   *   *   *   php /home/user/public_html/test/test.php

Comment: Can you please try with: */30 * * * * curl <YOUR DOMAIN NAME>/test/test.php

Answer (score 1):

You add your logic in some function where you don't use sessions, or which doesn't require any login to access.

Then in your cpanel u can create a cron job.

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33840196/how-to-create-a-cron-job-in-php-codeigniter/33840709#33840709) answer for more details.